# Java - Using Comparator to sort data scanned in from file

Tags: java

So I am working on writing code that will sort a list in various ways based on the Comaparable interface implemented by a class and also several Comparators. So I have a Student class and a Runner (for running the program). My issue is that I am importing data from the file, adding it to an arrayList, using a comparator to sort it, and then printing it out. When I do that I don't get the output that I should. When I print out the data write after importing it, it looks like:

```
Deirdre      70   62
Florence     37   90
Chris        60   68
Aaron        53   80
Elmer        91   40
Betty        79   50
```

^That is also what the txt file that I import looks like. And that is what the output needs to look similar to.

Instead the output looks like:

```
[Student@45ee12a7, Student@330bedb4, Student@2503dbd3, Student@4b67cf4d, Student@7ea987ac, Student@12a3a380]
```

This is the student class:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
private String name;
private int score1, score2;
public Student (String name, int score1, int score2){
    this.name = name;
    this.score1 = score1;
    this.score2 = score2; }
public String getName(){
    return name;  }
public int getScore1(){
    return score1;  }
public int getScore2(){
    return score2;  }
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return this.name.compareTo(o.name);  } }
```

The Runner class is:

```
public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File grades = new File("grades.txt");
    try{
        Scanner inScan = new Scanner(grades);
        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList();
        while(inScan.hasNext()){
            Student iS =  new Student (inScan.next(), inScan.nextInt(), inScan.nextInt());
            list.add(iS);
            System.out.printf("%-10s  %3d  %3d\n", iS.getName(), iS.getScore1(), iS.getScore2()); }
        System.out.println("=======================");
        Collections.sort(list,new CompareScore1());
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("=======================");
        Collections.sort(list, new CompareScore2());
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("=======================");
        Collections.sort(list, new CompareSum());
        System.out.println(list);  }

    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("File not found: " + "grades.txt");
        System.exit(1);  } }
public static class CompareScore1 implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getScore1() - o2.getScore1();  } }

public static class CompareScore2 implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getScore2() - o2.getScore2(); } }

public static class CompareSum implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getScore1() + o2.getScore2(); } }
```

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you expect it to print? Why?

Comment: You printing the `toString` representation of the `List` which is using the `toString` method of the elements.  To print the list in a formatted fashion, you will need to actually write some code, probably in a loop

Comment: I told you what I expected it to print. And because that is how I need for it to print. My question to you is what is this  a duplicate of? I searched and found nothing like this.

Comment: Refresh your page. So you expect it to print that because you need it to print that?

Comment: OK that took out a huge part of the problem but now when I print from the arrayList the answer comes out insde of [*answer*]. How do I get rid of the [].

Comment: If you want to print your own format, iterate through the elements of the list and print them any way you want.

Comment: don't know how to do that

Comment: [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: MadProgrammer...what? That helps with nothing.